# Asterisk- creating a call with originate command and pass parameter and set callerid

Tags: asterisk, phone-call, ivr, outbound

I want to generate an outbound call for this I am using outgoing command like

```
astreisk -rx "originate SIP/14075551234@sip-outbound extension s@auto-att"
```

I can generate a call with that but
How can I set callerid with this command and how can I pass parameter to my dialplan.When I used call file I used something like `Setvar:` but how can I use it with cmd originate.

I know I can use call file but I think cmd Originate would be faster just wondering how to set callerid and pass parameter with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use this command for any purpose except debug.

This command start new process every time you invoke it. That take REALLY alot of resource. Sure both call files and AMI originate methods are faster at least 100 times.

Comment: and I thought running a command would be faster my bad.Thanks for th reply .I have been also following your other thread they are very helpful.Can you help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31177111/getting-the-group-name-to-the-accoding-pri-port-in-asterisk) issue also it would be a great help